# Python Pandas .Apply Function to Vectorized Form

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert the following .apply transformation to a vectorized form which will run faster.  I've tried .where, and I've tried normal boolean indexing, however my solutions are not working.  Please send me in the right direction

```
oneDayDelta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
def correct_gps_datetimestamp(row):
    new_dts = row['GPS_DateTime']
    if row['Created'].hour == 0 and  row['GPS_DateTime'].hour > 10:
        new_dts = row['GPS_DateTime'] - oneDayDelta
    return(new_dts)

allData['GPS_DateTime'] = allData.apply(correct_gps_datetimestamp,axis=1)
```

Non working solution:

```
allData['GPS_DateTime'] = allData.where(allData['Created'].hour == 0 & allData['GPS_DateTime'].hour > 10,allData['GPS_DateTime'] - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single line using [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
allData['GPS_DateTime'] = np.where((allData['Created'].dt.hour == 0) &  (allData['GPS_DateTime'].dt.hour > 10), allData['GPS_DateTime'] - oneDayDelta, allData['GPS_DateTime'])
```

Note that the datetimes have [`dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) accessor to get the hours as int value, this allows you to compare the entire df, note that we use `&` here instead of `and` as we're comparing arrays. Additionally we have to use parentheses around the conditions due to operator precedence.

```
(allData['Created'].dt.hour == 0) &  (allData['GPS_DateTime'].dt.hour > 10)
```

So where this condition is met it returns your datetime column minus the one data timedelta, otherwise it just returns your column

Answer (score 2):

I think you need add `()` only to conditions:

```
(allData['Created'].hour == 0) & (allData['GPS_DateTime'].hour > 10)
```

---

```
allData['GPS_DateTime'] = allData.where((allData['Created'].hour == 0) & 
                                        (allData['GPS_DateTime'].hour > 10),
                                        allData['GPS_DateTime'] - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```